# How are multiple Android Tween AlphaAnimations applied together?

Tags: android, animation

I have a simple Android application consisting of a single ImageView. A Tween animation is applied to the image when the user taps on the screen, intended to cause it to fade away and then fade back in, and that animation is described in an XML file within the res/anim directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="1000"
    />

    <alpha
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="1000"
    />

</set>
```

What actually occurs is that the image fades away for one second, and then remains invisible for another second until the animation completes, when it reappears suddenly instead of the gradual effect I am going for.
No documentation appears to properly describe how the animations are applied in this type of case.

From playing around, I've noticed that the transformations do run simultaneously, multiplying alpha values together, and that the the second animation does apply from the start if the 'fillBefore' attribute is not set, despite the 'startOffset' being intended to delay its effect.

How can I cause the second animation to fade in the image rather than it suddenly reappearing at the end?

Comment: tween animations sux (property animations rox), do you really have to use them?

Comment: I'll go there if I have to, but I don't understand why something so seemingly simple is more complicated than the API docs let on. It should be possible.

Comment: ok so good luck ;-)